# How to stop uncompiled data from being seen, without the use of ng-cloak?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, data-binding

I have built a web application and am trying to incorporate the AngularJS Framework into my code. I have set up my program so that I have an `<input type="number"/>` with an `ng-model="subtotal.subtotal1"` directive and a `<td>` element with a data binding element as the following `{{subtotal.subtotal1}}`. 
The problem within this data binding expression is that when the window initially loads you can see the uncompiled data briefly before the actual value is returned from my javascript file(meaning I see the curly brackets momentarily) 
**Here is what I have tried in order to fix my problem:**
 1.Move the angular.js CDN file to the end of the body section and in the head section. 
2. Changed the order of the javascript files I have included 
3. Used `ng-cloak`, which does not work cross browser (IE:Google Chrome) and looks as if the page has a glitch. I would rather not use a directive to solve this issue, if I was forced to do so then I would resort to simply displaying the values in the `<td id="one">` element using something like this: `document.getElementById("one").innerHTML="content"`. Although I know I could do this without Angular.js the **point of this exercise is to use Angular**

I have included the code in the `<head>` section and `<body>` section which could possibly be the issue(data-binding, links to javascript files, and the respective javascript file including the angular code)
**head**:

```
<html ng-app="myModule1">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="vex/dist/css/vex.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vex/dist/css/vex-theme-os.css"/> <br><br>
```

**div tag:**

 (this tag is contained within the body tag and includes the `ng-controller`,the `<input type="number" ng-model="subtotal.subtotal1"/>`, and the respective `<td>{{1.99*subtotal.subtotal1}}</td>`:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="mycontroller1">
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                <form id="medication-product-1" method="POST">  
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td data-th="Product">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <img id="small-pic2" src="images/benadryl.png"></img>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <h4 class="nomargin"><input type="hidden" name="name1" value="Benadryl">
                                                Benadryl</input>    
                                            </h4>
                                            <p>
                                                A medication which reduces itching, sneezing, coughing through because of its properties as an anti-histamine.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>  
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Price"><input type="hidden" name="Price1" value=01.99> 
                                    $1.99</input>
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Quantity">
                                    <input type="number" ng-model="subtotal.subtotal1" ng-init="subtotal.subtotal1=0" name="Quantity1" ng-change="changed()" id="amount1" class="form-control text-center" min="0"/>
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Subtotal" id="subtotal-1" name="Subtotal"  class="text-center">{{1.99*subtotal.subtotal1}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1"></input>
                                    <button type="button" id="button1" name="button-1" class="btn btn-primary">
                                         Add To Cart<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </form> 
                    <form id="medication-product-2" method="POST">
                            <tr>
                                <td data-th="Product">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <img src="images/motrin.jpg" id="small-pic"></img>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <h4 >
                                            <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="Motrin"></input>
                                                Motrin 
                                            </h4>
                                            <p>
                                                Pain Reliever and Fever Reducer 
                                            </p>
                                        </div>  
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Price">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Price2" value="3.99">
                                    $3.99
                                </input>    
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Quantity">
                                    <input type="number" ng-model="subtotal.subtotal2" ng-change="changed2()" ng-init="subtotal.subtotal2=0" name="Quantity2"
                                     id="amount2" min="0" class="form-control text-center"></input>
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Subtotal" id="subtotal-2" 
                                name="Subtotal" class="text-center" >{{3.99*subtotal.subtotal2}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2"></input>
                                    <button type="button2" id="button2" name="button-2"  class="btn btn-primary">
                                         Add To Cart<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                        </tbody>
                    </form> 
                </table>
            </div>
```

**End Of Body Tag:**

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/medication.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="vex/dist/js/vex.combined.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" vex.defaultOptions.className = 'vex-theme-os'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/signout.js"></script>
    </body>
```

**medication.js: Portion of the javascript file with the angular code in it.**

```
window.onload=function(){
button1=document.getElementById("button1");
button2=document.getElementById("button2");
number1=document.getElementById("amount1");
number2=document.getElementById("amount2");
number2.value=0;
number1.value=0;
button1.disabled=true;
button2.disabled=true;

var medicine=angular.module("myModule1",[])
.controller("mycontroller1",function($scope){
        var subtotal={
            subtotal1:0,
            subtotal2:0

        }
    $scope.subtotal=subtotal;

        $scope.changed=function(){
        if(subtotal.subtotal1>0){
            button1.disabled=false;
        }
        else {
            button1.disabled=true;
        }

        }

    $scope.changed2=function(){
        if(subtotal.subtotal2>0){
            button2.disabled=false;
        }
        else{
            button2.disabled=true;
        }

    }

});
```

Again I do not know why I can see the curly braces in the td element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `ng-bind` instead of `{{}}` but I find it easier to write `{{}}` and just use `ng-cloak` as it is designed for this purpose.

Just add ng-cloak high enough in the tree so you don't have to add it to very many elements

Change

```
<td>{{1.99*subtotal.subtotal1}}</td>
```

To

```
<td ng-bind="(1.99*subtotal.subtotal1)"></td>
```